# Позиционирование элементов в библиотеке FlowTextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть разметка:

```
   <uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView

        android:id="@+id/ftv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvProfilesTitle">

        <Button
            style="?attr/btnStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
            android:text="@string/button_add"
            android:id="@+id/btnProfilesAdd"
            android:onClick="addProfile"/>

    </uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>
```

`FlowTextView` - это спец. `TextView`, текст которого обтекает кнопку, как на картинке:
[image]

Мне нужно, чтобы кнопка была всегда прижата к `ListView`, который ниже.

Разработчик `FlowTextView` сделал так, что отступ кнопки сверху регулируется `marginTop`-ом.
Но в зависимости от размера шрифта (`textSize` в sp) и поворота экрана в `FlowTextView` отображается от `2` до `8` строк. Соответственно `marginTop` должен быть от `0` до какой-то вычисленной величины. Затем я задаю его с помощью:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) btnProfilesAdd.getLayoutParams();
                btnParams.setMargins(0, mTop, 8, 0);
```

Итак, вопрос: как мне вычислить эту величину для задания `marginTop`-а?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ru.**********"
style="?attr/mainBackground">

<TextView
    style="?attr/tvTitle"
    android:id="@+id/tvProfilesTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/list_profiles_title"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView

    android:id="@+id/ftv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvProfilesTitle"
    >

    <Button
        style="?attr/btnStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:text="@string/button_add"
        android:id="@+id/btnProfilesAdd"
        android:onClick="addProfile"/>

</uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>

<ListView
    style="?attr/lvAll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/lvProfilesList"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ftv"
     />

<TextView
    style="?attr/tvCaptions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/list_profiles_in_app_caption"
    android:id="@+id/tvProfilesInAppCaptions"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lvProfilesList"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:id="@+id/llProfilesButtons">

    <Button
        style="?attr/btnStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/but_save"
        android:id="@+id/butProfilesSave"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="profilesSave"/>

   <Button
        style="?attr/btnStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/but_close"
        android:id="@+id/butProfilesClose"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="profilesClose"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: К сожалению я не знаю, как решить вашу проблему с помощью только разметки.

Answer (score 3):

Класс [`FlowTextView`](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView/blob/master/flowtextview/src/main/java/uk/co/deanwild/flowtextview/FlowTextView.java) наследуется от `RelativeLayout`, соответственно в нем применимы все возможности позиционирования для этого контейнера, в частности,чтобы прижать виджет внутри контейнера в левый нижний угол:

```
<uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView

    android:id="@+id/ftv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvProfilesTitle">

    <Button
        style="?attr/btnStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:text="@string/button_add"
        android:id="@+id/btnProfilesAdd"
        android:onClick="addProfile"/>

</uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>
```

атрибуты `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` и `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

PS: значения `sp` (независимые от масштаба пиксели) [указываются только для шрифтов](http://www.pandacoder.com/android_dimension_px_sp_dp/), чтобы они могли учитывать пользовательстельские предпочтения размера шрифта в настройках устройства, расстояния на разметке указываются в `dp`

Comment: При добавлении таких атрибутов моя кнопка "падает" глубоко вниз ...

Comment: @Alexey не могли бы вы более понятно описать проблему, позиционируйте вложенные элементы как в обычном контейнере `RelativeLayout`

Comment: подробнее так - после добавления атрибутов android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" и android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" к кнопке результат на скриншоте:
http://uploadme.ru/image/6OI

Comment: Приложите в вопрос всю разметку полностю.

Comment: @ pavlofff, спасибо Вам за участие. Вот полная разметка:

Comment: @Alexey Добавьте разметку в вопрос, нажав ссылку "править" под вопросом.

Comment: @ pavlofff, приложил разметку к вопросу. Очень хочется решить проблему "правильно", без написания кастомной функции-костыля...